# Ad management system in PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, content-management-system, ads

I have created a website in PHP, now I want to add ad support there. Clients request for ads at some fixed locations in the website, they provide there ad in a fixed size.

I am looking for a CMS or Script which is able to manage ads, as per the ad area in the site. It should be able to manage that if an ad needs to be run for 10 days then that ad will be displayed there for 10 days and after that it will randomly pick the ads for that particular area.

Do anyone know any such CMS which offers such kind of facility, open-source CMS will be better but if there is any paid CMS for such functionality, then that's fine.

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going with http://www.clippersoft.net/ this software. Thanks!

Comment: What's your opinion about this service?

Comment: I used this about 3 years back and at that time the software was good with lot of custom features and also we can modify it as per our need if we want.

Comment: does not support mobile platforms iOS and Android

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [OpenX](http://openx.com/)

Could be used community hosted or as an open source software on your server.

Comment: +1, pretty simple to use, even if you install the software on your own server, and very powerful.

Comment: I have found http://www.clippersoft.net/ I am not intrested in to develop an Ad Network. It just ad management system for my website, I can create ads and generate code and put them on my website. That's it. Please suggest any other software like http://www.clippersoft.net/

Comment: They have many versions: http://www.openx.org/advertiser/compare-ad-server-products , and I am not getting for which I should go, as per my requirements?

Comment: OpenX Source if you want to host it yourself and OpenX OnRamp if they should host it for free (limited ad impressions per month)

Comment: Nowadays, OpenX did not provide open source anymore and its website has no signup account too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) offers a very good ads plugins. I suggest you to check it out :)